# Label control's MaxLine and LineBreakMode properties are not working properly

Tags: maui

To limit maximum lines of Label and indicate text truncation we use `MaxLines` and `LineBreakMode` properties of the `Label` control.

This works fine in Xamarin.Forms but in .NET MAUI it's not working.

#### MainPage.xaml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Maui_POC.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                HeightRequest="200"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label
                Text="Hello, World!"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                FontSize="32"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label
                Text="Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App UI, Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                FontSize="18"
                MaxLines="2"
                LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Button
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

#### Expected output:

It should show the `Label` with two lines and at the end of second line it will show '...' like this.
But in MAUI it's not working that way in both Android & iOS. In Android it does shows ellipsis but not the second line.

How to fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/5093

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9084

Comment: This issue still exists in .Net Maui 8. Surprised that this is not fixed for very long time.  Information mentioned in "Expected Output" above is very basic and important Usecase.

Answer (score 3):

If you set a value for WidthRequest, then you can state how the text will be handled if it is too long with LineBreakMode. TailTruncation will add ellipsis (three dots) to the end of the text if it won't fit in the space specified by WidthRequest. For example:

```
 <Label x:Name="lblCityName"
          Text="{Binding CityName, Mode=OneWay}"
          FontSize="24"
          WidthRequest="260"
          LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
          Margin="5,0,0,0"
          Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.Column="0"
          />
```

Other options for LineBreakMode can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.linebreakmode?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: Fixed WidthRequest is not good solution. Because every device will have different screen size.

Comment: WidthRequest uses what Microsoft call “device independent pixels”

Comment: You can try to predict the size with some math in the code behind `LabelWidth = Math.Floor(DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width / DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density);`

Comment: Now, I'm a bit more experience with .NET MAUI, I no longer bother to add WidthRequest and let the system work it out.